# Jquery Validate addMethod "notEqual" causes browser crash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", 
    function(value, element, param) {
        return this.optional(element) || value !== param;
    }, 
    "Please specify a different (non-default) value"
);
```

then:

```
$(this).validate({
    rules: {
        address: { notEqual: "ADDRESS" },
        building: { notEqual: "BUILDING"}
    },
    submitHandler: function() { 
        $(this).submit(); 
    }
});
```

To make fields not equal to their default values, but this causes browsers to be very slow, or crash in the case of webkit engines.

```
jQuery JavaScript Library v1.8.3
jQuery validation plug-in pre-1.5.2
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong?

Update: 
I just tried to replace the validation plug-in to: jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.11.1, still the same result.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/aVy9e/

Comment: A demo on jsfiddle.net would really help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aVy9e/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the `submit` event recursively from the `submitHandler` option. Instead, call the native submit function on the form element:

```
$(this).validate({
    rules: {
        address: { notEqual: "ADDRESS" },
        building: { notEqual: "BUILDING"}
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) { 
        form.submit(); 
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/aVy9e/2/

Comment: Dude, you just send me your photo, I need to make a statue for you
Thank you very much it works like magic